# Не открывается база данных Qt5

Tags: mysql, qt5, mysqlconnector

В первом окне база данных открывается, записывает данные, все нормально (только русские символы не читает, ? кидает. Но это другая тема), теперь пробую подключить с другого окна уже другой переменной БД, подключение свое тоже писал, база просто не открывается. В логах выводит

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'second' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
> QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'second', old connection removed.

то есть как я понял, оно открывается, но функции не работают, например QMessageBox не выводит

```
if(db.isOpen())
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Ok", "База данных подключена");
}
```

Comment: Для каждого набора данных (для каждого окна) открывай своё соединение с БД.

Comment: Так и делаю, в первом окне стандартное соединение, во втором 'second'

Comment: Система считает иначе: *duplicate connection name 'second'*.

Comment: У меня подключение идет через нажатие кнопки, я ее нажимал пару раз, при первом нажатии такого нет